# Consulta Sobre Algebra Relacional

Tags: base-de-datos

Me dan las siguientes tablas:

```
Producto<nombreProducto, tipo, precio, esParaDiabetico, esDietetico>
Persona<DNI, nombre, edad, estadoCivil, profesion>
Fabrica<nombreProducto, nombreFabrica, produccionEnPesos, ciudad>
Regalos<DNIRegalador, DNiReceptor, nombreProducto, fecha>
```

Como puedo saber todos los productos que han sido regalados a todas la personas existentes en la base de datos?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

**Paso no. 1**

Por cada producto, calcular cuantas receptor unicas han sido recibido este producto (se guarda en el columno *countReceptorUnico*).
Se logra con la consulta:

```sql
SELECT nombreProducto, COUNT(DISTINCT(DNiReceptor)) AS countReceptorUnico
FROM Regalos
GROUP BY nombreProducto
```

**Paso no. 2**

Si el countReceptorUnico de esto producto es igual que el numero de persona unica en la tabla `Persona`, significa que el producto ha sido regalados a todas las personas en la BBDD.
La consulta final es:

```sql
SELECT nombreProducto FROM
(
    -- paso #1
    SELECT nombreProducto, COUNT(DISTINCT(DNiReceptor)) AS countReceptorUnico
    FROM Regalos
    GROUP BY nombreProducto

) AS t1
WHERE t1.countReceptorUnico = 
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(DNI)) FROM Persona) -- contar el numero de persona unica
```